# Flask 'in app' redirect aka forward

Tags: python, redirect, flask, web-frameworks, forward

Is it possible to do 'in app' redirect in Flask app like in old poor Symfony 1? I mean if during of processing one request I decide to change my view function (by some condition) and I don't want to do real redirect can I call something like `forward(*other_view_name*)`?

Comment: Why don't you try it? Views are just functions, so just do `return name_of_other_view_function()`..

Comment: Hm, I'm already doing simple call of another view function, but it is not convenient enough. I.e. default parameters of route missed, I should write `return other_view_name()` but in case or `redirect` exceptions do this job for me and so on.

Comment: But for a redirect you'd *also* need to provide path parameters. This is no different, just pass in the arguments. Refactor your view function to use `keyword_argument=default` for path defaults, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks! I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy of [Martijn Pieters'](https://stackoverflow.com/u/100297) answer in the comment section:

> Why don't you try it? Views are just functions, so just do
>
> ```
> return name_of_other_view_function()
> ```